How do I make my "Please select..." unselectable in Contact Form 7?
How would I make the "Please select..." option in my drop-down menu unselectable? I am coding in this form tester for Contact Form 7 Conditional Fields. This is an example portion of my code with no conditional code for simplicity:
<label>
  How far along is the borrower in acquiring the property? 
  The borrower… <span>*</span>
</label>
  [select* property-ownership-how-far-along-is-the-borrower-in-
acquiring-the-property-the-borrower first_as_label 
"Please select…" 
"is still looking for a property to acquire." 
"has identified the property." 
"has made an offer to purchase the property." 
"has the property under contract to purchase." 
"already owns the property."] 

I know first_as_label is supposed to do exactly what I'm complaining about, but it literally just isn't, I am still able to select "Please select...".
Edit: I found the fix, put the below script anywhere in your code and replace first_as_label with class:wpcf7-select (but remember to change 'Please select...' to whatever your first option is).
<script>
(function ($) {
   'use strict';
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var $select = $('.wpcf7-select');
       $select.each(function(e){
         var first_option = $(this).find('option').first();
         if(first_option.attr('value') == 'Please select…'){
           first_option.attr('disabled', true);
         }
     })
  });
})(jQuery)
</script>


I would put the attribute disabled on the option that needs to be disabled if you are working in HTML.

I am pretty sure my code is HTML. Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by "I will put the attribute disabled on the option that you need that needs to be disabled"

"I will put the attribute disabled on the option that you need that needs to be disabled"
I mean that if the code is like (for example):
Example
Select 1
Select 2
Select 3

And you need to disable the second option, you can do in this way:
Select 2
And when you will click the text that will displays the input, you will notice that the second option has the color gray. If you do not get it, comment!
I know that looks bad in the comment but I tried to explain

Sorry for the misunderstanding, I am not looking to change the HTML directly, because my HTML is generated by Contact Form 7. I am trying to figure out how to make CF7’s tag first_as_label function properly.

No problem Albert, I tried to help you, have a good day!
